# Отформатировать флешку защищенную от записи на macOs Catalina

Tags: macos, mac

Создал загрузочную флешку с macOs Ventura через OpenCore Patcher. Теперь не могу отформатировать флешку на macOs через дисковую утилиту, вылезает ошибка - Не удалось открыть устройство. : (-69877), пробовал на винде, но там флешка защищена от записи и тоже никак не получилось ее отформатировать. Пробовал через терминал на винде и macOs, пробовал на винде через HP USB Disk Storage Format Tool, на macOs через SD card formatter, но везде ошибка, что диск защищен от записи. Флешка самая обычная Smartbuy 32gb без каких-либо переключателей на корпусе, до этого проблем с ней никогда не было. Кто-нибудь с таким сталкивался ранее?

Comment: ну, попробуйте записать нули в первые несколько килобайт этого блочного устройства. (как это сделать под ms/windows или apple/macos — понятия не имею. ищите в интернетах).

Comment: под gnu/linux или freebsd как-нибудь так: `$ head -c 2K /dev/zero > /dev/нужное.блочное.устройство`. впрочем в этих операционных системах и просто снести/создать таблицу разделов — вряд ли что-то помешает.